# Undeletable directory in lost+found

Tags: permissions, ext4, fsck, ownership, data-corruption

How can I delete this directory? I did `fsck` and it has found some garbage, I looked through these files and there wasn't something important. So I've tried to delete the contents of `/lost+found` and everything has gone except this strange directory. I thought that putting it to `/tmp` (I can move that dir across the volume) will erase it on next reboot but it's still there after both reboot and another `fsck`.

**As it seems like the problem is low level and playing with ownership and permissions is not enough, I've made you able to reproduce the issue by yourself. Enjoy!**

- **This is safe, you will be able to umount image to get rid of these directories on your machine**;
- **This s not iso-image, this is the result of `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/files/broken.iso`**;

I've made a 15MB archive with the image which is ~1.2GB. You can download and ply with it with the following commands:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22701362/broken.tar.xz
tar xvf broken.tar.xz
mkdir test
sudo mount broken.iso test
cd test
```

There would be two directories (During the creation of that image it appears that there are two such directories on my disk):

```
/tmp/test> tree
.
├── 1
│   └── plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar.sha1 [error opening dir]
└── 2
    └── #1589030 [error opening dir]

4 directories, 0 files
```

Good luck with removing these two directories:

```
/tmp/test> sudo rm -rf *
rm: cannot remove '1/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar.sha1': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '2/#1589030': Operation not permitted

/tmp/test> sudo chown -R root:root *
chown: changing ownership of '1/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar.sha1': Operation not permitted
chown: cannot read directory '2/#1589030': Permission denied

/tmp/test> sudo chmod -R 777 *
chmod: changing permissions of '1/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar.sha1': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '2/#1589030': Operation not permitted
chmod: cannot read directory '2/#1589030': Permission denied
```

Comment: How is `/tmp` on the same volume? Could you post the output of `df`? Also, please post the output of `sudo perl -MFile::Path -e 'rmtree("/tmp/foo") || die "$!"'` just in case we get a more informative error message.

Comment: @terdon I've added the output to the question. Do you think the output is even a bit helpful?

Comment: Well, the `df` output shows us that your /tmp` is actually a normal directory on `/` and not a tmpfs which is the default setup. That's surprising, but explains both why you could copy the dir to `/tmp` and why it survives reboots. The `perl` output doesn't really add much, no, but it was worth a shot. I'm clutching at straws here.

Comment: offtopic: in Ubuntu `/tmp` is a normal directory by default. This is done to prevent filling it up to 100% and to save RAM. It is cleaned up during the startup. This behaviour exists for a long time.

Comment: I'd try booting off a livecd, then poking around the filesystem.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek that didn't help either. However, I am in progress of creating reproducible environment. As soon as I complete cloning/erasing and compressing the partition I'll provide the steps in the question.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek you can now try removing that dir youself if you have a spare minute. I've added steps-to-reproduce into the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility is the immutable flag in the case of ext filesystem. See output of `lsattr` command. If there is `i` present, it can be removed with `chattr -i filename`

> A  file  with the 'i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be
>   deleted or renamed, no link can be created to this file and no data
>   can be written  to  the  file. Only the superuser or a process
>   possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this
>   attribute.

In this case, there is something else happening

This seems to work,

```
> lsattr 1
-----a---------- 1/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar.sha1
> rmdir 1/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar.sha1
rmdir: failed to remove '1/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar.sha1': Operation not permitted
> chattr -a 1/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar.sha1
> rmdir 1/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar.sha1

> lsattr 2
---D-ad--j--T--- 2/#1589030 
> chattr -D -a -d -j -T 2/\#1589030
> rmdir 2/\#1589030
```

Comment: Nope. Did you see that I used `sudo`? I would appreciate if you download the image, mount it and try yourself.

Comment: This is not an 'iso image' this is result of `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=broken.iso`

Comment: Yes, you are probably right, sorry! Did you have a chance to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yes, and it looks really odd.

Comment: I feel sooo stupid now :( But you are my hero of the day, mr. J.J. Hakala

Comment: I was too quick. I've deleted the first directory with your help, but the second one gives me: `sudo chattr -D -a -d -j -T 2/\#1589030` : 
`chattr: Permission denied while reading flags on 2/#1589030` :(

Comment: @Grief I cannot reproduce that problem with directory 2, those commands work for me.

Comment: I understand. But on my system it's reproducible even with the downloaded and mounted image, I mean everything is the same for you and me except the system. Maybe there is a bug still?

Comment: I decided to accept your answer and create a separate one regarding `lsattr` issue. Thank you for your help! Here is a new question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/794371/lsattr-permission-denied-while-reading-flags-on-directory

Comment: if you haven't been setting immutable yourself then at this point it might be  better to backup and recreate the filesystem, if its had enough damage to flip bits like that its probably not trustable and probably will be slower in usage

Answer (score 1):

try becoming the user that owns it to delete it

```
sudo -u 6666 -g 19312 rm -rf ./#1589030
```

Comment: `sudo -u '#6666' -g '#19311' rm -rf \#1589030`
`rm: cannot remove '#1589030': Permission denied`
`sudo -u '#6666' -g '#19311' chmod 777 \#1589030`
`chmod: cannot access '#1589030': Permission denied`

Comment: You need to make than user if it doesn't exist

Comment: creating user and group with these UID and GID didn't help