# Sudo - Understanding of what it does

Tags: sudo

This is just me wanting to understand 'sudo' better.

I am logged in to my Ubuntu 18.04LTS machine as 'alan' which is a normal user, and is a member of the 'sudo' group:

```
$ groups
alan adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

First I did this (I have correctly entered my password):

```
sudo touch /lost+found/test.file
```

I get these:

```
$ ls /lost+found/
ls: cannot open directory '/lost+found/': Permission denied
```

and

```
$ sudo ls /lost+found/
test.file
```

That is completely what I would expect.  However, I don't understand why I get this:

```
$ sudo -u alan ls /lost+found/
ls: cannot open directory '/lost+found/': Permission denied
```

Why can't I run an 'admin' command, as myself, if I am a member of the sudo group, and I have entered my password?

Clearly I don't understand how 'sudo', or more specifically, 'sudo -u' works :-)

Comment: Smells like a possible permission issue: Show us the complete output of `ls -l /` in your question above.

Comment: $ sudo ls -l /lost+found/

total 0

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr  4 14:02 test.file

Comment: `sudo -u alan ` won't give superuser privileges. This will switch to user alan. This comes handy when you want to execute commands as other normal user.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you think of `sudo ls` as shorthand for `sudo -u root ls`? The privileges you get are *those of the target user*

Comment: @Kuffy:  Do you mean that sudo -u ONLY switches temporarily to a different user?  Is it meaningless to use sudo -u alan (when logged in as alan)?

Comment: @steeldriver:  Do you mean that, as 'alan' does not have permission to read /lost+found, running the ls command via sudo -u still won't give 'alan' that permission?  If so, what is the point of 'sudo -u'?

Comment: @Alan Absolutely. You answered yourself :)

Comment: @Kuffy:  Okay - Thanks :-)

Comment: `sudo -u username` runs the command as a user but not switching to the user.  Once the command is done the shell is back to the logged in user.  `sudo su - username` will switch to the user, since `su` is used for switch user.  However, `su - root` will not switch to the root user by default in Ubuntu since the `root` user is disabled by default.  `sudo su - root` will switch to the root user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undeletable directory in lost+found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794262/undeletable-directory-in-lostfound)

Comment: Hi All - Yes, I think I understand how.  Thank you to everyone :-)  Not sure how to close off the question, when all the answers have been posted as 'comments' rather than answers though?